# How do i access the height of a single bar from a chart and change it?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I am working with a powerpoint bar chart.
Within this chart there is a bar which I need the height from.
Somehow I dont find the right object/property to refer to.
The Microsoft Documentation was not helpful so far.
Kindest Regards,
AlphaKay

Comment: `pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Height` with pptPres being a set `PowerPoint.Presentation` variable.

Comment: Do you want the height, or the Y value? @JvdV gave you the height. To get the value, you need to get the array of all Y values, then get the one for the point youre interested in. So `Dim vYVals As Variant : vYVals = pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values : MyValue = vYVals(PointIndex)`